# Catch HTTP client errors in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, guzzle

How do you catch errors thrown by the [HTTP client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client) (for example a time out) so that it doesn't throw the curl error in the Laraval debugger (in debug mode) before you can do anything with the error to avoid stopping the execution?

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
    try {
        $request = Http::post('https://example.com/post', [
        'password' => 'guest']);

    } catch(ConnectException $e)
    {
        //log error
    }

    //continue with another mode
```

Instead, I'm always getting the Laravel's Ignition error page

```
Illuminate\Http\Client\ConnectionException
cURL error 28: Failed to connect to example.com port 443: Timed out
```

and the error is not caught by my code. Is it possible that the laravel debugger always have priority and can't be overridden in debug mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is almost certainly a namespacing issue.

You'll need either this at the top of the file:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Client\ConnectionException;
```

or do this:

```
} catch(\Illuminate\Http\Client\ConnectionException $e)
```

Otherwise, you're actually trying to catch something in the *current* namespace named `ConnectionException` (i.e. something like `App\Controllers\ConnectionException`), which will never exist.

Comment: Hi, only the second method works but I would prefer the first, do you know why?

Comment: No; I'd suspect you made a mistake somewhere (typo?) if that's the case.

Comment: Although I am on Laravel 9, in my case both of them fail... :(
I see `local.ERROR: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host:` and my `catch` block not working...

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks.