# Laravel - cURL exceception - try catch not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, guzzle, laravel-9, laravel-http-client

It seems that the issue I am facing is straightforward but somehow the resolutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69649975/laravel-correct-way-to-catch-curl-exceception), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72494753/laravel-9-http-client-exception-handling), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64850393/catch-http-client-errors-in-laravel-8) are not working

I have got the following piece of code:

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

...

try {

  $response = Http::timeout(3)->get('google.cim');

} catch (\Illuminate\Http\Client\ConnectionException $e) {

  Log::info('Connection refused #6 ');

}
```

I have already tried

1. Using `\Illuminate\Http\Client\ConnectionException $e`
2. Using `\Exception $e`
3. Clearing cache `php artisan optimize:clear`

But I just see the exception in the logs while my custom message never appears in the log.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you reviewed the stack trace from the error log to see if the error is being generated/logged somewhere you're not expecting? The above code is working as expected in isolation (i.e. your custom message is logged).

Comment: @Peppermintology thank you for trying to help me out... if it works for you then my suspicion of `cache` being the culprit becomes stronger but alas even clearing them don't work on my end. To answer your question, I am looking at the same log where all my other custom logging is being done which is `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Sorry, when I say generated/logged somewhere you're not expecting, I mean in your code. So the or a similar exception is being thrown somewhere other than the above code.

Comment: Double checked... that's not the case

Comment: Can you share the stack trace, or error message you see in the logs?

Comment: @BernardWiesner I see the whole Exception (`ocal.ERROR: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host:` and `[previous exception] [object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ConnectException(code: 0): cURL error 6: Could not resolve host:`) getting printed in the log while I am expecting just the string `Connection refused #6` instead, that I am logging

Comment: The full stack trace should contain your class name, if it does not it might come from elsewhere the error.

Comment: You can easily debug it, just add a dd("works") just before your Http::get, and see if it works.

Comment: Catching \Exception $e should work in your case

Comment: If you see the exception in your logs, then there is a full stack trace in your logs. As others have requested, share the stack trace from your logs.

Comment: thanks @BernardWiesner ... the solution I found disappointingly can't really be called one as it was a cache issue after all... it was resolved only after I restarted everything (including the machine). Your suggestion of adding dd (although I used a log) helped me though.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than catching a specific exception, try catching all exceptions using:

```
try {
    $response = Http::timeout(3)->get('google.cim');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    Log::info($e->getMessage()); 
}
```

Also, check your `config/logging.php` file to make sure your logging `level` is set correctly. It should be `debug` or `info`:

```
'daily' => [
    'driver' => 'daily',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
    'level' => 'debug',
    'days' => 14,
],
```

Don't forget to clear the config cache if you need to make change. Run: `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time... however there was nothing in your reply that I haven't already tried and I mentioned it too in my comment except for explicitly checking the logs settings which was anyway implicitly confirmed.